# Blenrig 5 Deform Cage isn't symmetrical

Tags: rigging

I'm new to rigging. I saw the videos for Blenrig on the cloud so I downloaded it and watched all the videos. Everything seems ok except for the deform cage, which is not symmetrical. I wouldn't have too much of a problem with it except for the fact that the x-axis mirroring seems to be permanent, so when I adjust a misplaced vertex on one side it screws up the properly placed vertex on the other side, so that I can never get a symmetrical [image]

Is there any way to either turn off the x-axis mirroring, fix it, then turn it back on? Or a way to make sure it is symmetrical in the first place? Using Blenrig 5 and Blender 2.78c.

Comment: did you bake those meshes and armature as well? Make sure when you bake the armature, all layers has content mesh "mdef_cage" and "proxy_model" are visible.

Answer (score 1):

By the time I posted this question I'd already been fighting this problem for a day, but not being one to just sit around waiting for an answer, I kept looking around and trying things.

This has something to do with the scaling. My original model was very large -more than 20x the size of the default Blenrig armature. When I scaled the model down to a size pretty close to the default rig size it all came out fine.

Since extensive searches on multiple boards yielded zero answers I figured I'd answer my own question here in case anyone else has the problem. If anyone comes up with any details about the scaling issue or a way to bypass that problem please let us know!